# Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: c#, .net, docker, mailkit

First, for some context: I am using .NetCore to develop an API with Identity. Everything is on a Cloud server, inside a Docker. When a user is created, an email is sent to the new User using a mailkit and the webmail server through Plesk (Hosted on the same machine). The docker is accessed via a redirection trough Apache using a ProxyPass from the subdomain to the port on localhost

Everything works great while debugging trough JetBrain's Rider, but it is not able to process the email in the docker on the server.

Here is the stack:

```
System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000001, 11): Resource temporarily unavailable
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName)
   at System.Net.Dns.ResolveCallback(Object context)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(Exception source)
   at System.Net.Dns.HostResolutionEndHelper(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Dns.EndGetHostAddresses(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Dns.<>c.<GetHostAddressesAsync>b__25_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
```

I have yet to try and run the docker on another linux machine to test.
One of my current guess would be a problem with the SSL certificate, but I don't think it would cause a problem with the DNS or any internal socket.

Another guess is thats its a problem for the Docker to get the DNS Hostname, but since it works ok in a local.

Edit: I tried multiple time to run the docker on the mac and the error is still triggered once in a while but not always. It is although always triggered on the server and never send the email

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After two weeks of research, I finally stumbled upon a solution for this:

The problem is related to the network, that was obvious, but it's precisely about how containers are isolated from one another. Problem is, the container has no outbound connection. A solution that work inside a standalone container is to use the `--network host` parameter, which would expose the host network to the container. Note that using this would remove the port mapping from the container since the container's port 5000 is now linked to the host's port 5000

Hope this solution can help others